# How to open a new tab with changing working directory with Conemu

Tags: conemu

I'm using `ConEmu` with `nyaos`.
When new tab is opened, I want to set same directory for new tab's working directory.

If I open a new tab by command `nayos.exe -new_console`, then working directory is changed as I expected.

So I created a new macro from `Settings->Keys & Macro` like this.

`print(\enyaos.exe -new_console\n)`

This macro opens a new tab, but working directory stays default.

How can I open a new tab by keeping same working directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying wrong syntax. Proper syntax is thoroughly explained in [wiki](http://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/GuiMacro)

```
print("\enyaos.exe -new_console\n")
```

Also, you may use macro without need of "print"

```
Shell("new_console:I")
```

Comment: It works now, thanks! There was also another mistake that I made, I was trying to assign key to `Ctrl+T` that is already taken.